# Oscillatory entropic integral evaluation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, oscillatory-integral

I need to evaluate the following multidimensional integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxdpdwdz\; e^{x^2+p^2-aw^2-az^2-ib(xz-pw)} \ln(2(p+z)^2+2(x+w)^2-1)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are known numerical parameters and can be plugged in. Since the integrand is even, I can rewrite:

$$2 \int_{0}^{\infty}dxdpdwdz\; e^{x^2+p^2-aw^2-az^2-ib(xz-pw)} \ln(2(p+z)^2+2(x+w)^2-1)$$

The integrant is highly oscillatory. I have never dealt with this kind of problems before. I was wondering if anyone can advise me on a direction. Maybe, there is a shortcut or some hammer-method to approach this problem. If it is hopeless, please, also let me know.

P.S.: I know that the result is supposed to be real. Also, when I use (probably, wrongly) a [MonteCarlo-type integration](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature), I get zero if the integration interval is sufficiently large ~[0, 60]. However, I know that this method is not supposed to work here...

Comment: Are you actually integrating over $\mathbb{R}^4$? You mentioned that this is a multidimensional integral, but both $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots$ and $2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dots$ suggest that you are recognizing them as one-dimensional integral. Also, this integral does not converge absolutely due to the fast growth of $(x,p)\mapsto e^{x^2+p^2}$. Then, similar to the Riemann rearrangement theorem, the order of integration matters (in both the convergence and the value!), and I believe that you need to first integrate w.r.t. $w$ and $z$ to get a finite value.

Comment: Judging by its look, I guess that the integral has arisen in physics, in which one must have some physical intuition as to how the integral should be set up. Revealing that context may greatly improve your posting as a mathematics question, especially thinking that the integral in its current expression is not well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $\frac{b^2}{4} > a > 1$ and interpret the expression as the following conditonally converget iterated integral:

$$ I := \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}p_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}p_2 \, e^{x_1^2+p_1^2-a(x_2^2+p_2^2) - ib(x_1p_2 - x_2p_1)} \log\left(2(x_1+x_2)^2+2(p_1+p_2)^2-1\right), $$

where $\log$ is the principal complex logarithm. Then substituting $(x_2,p_2) \mapsto (x_2-x_1, p_2-p_1)$,

$$ I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}p_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}p_2 \, e^{-(a-1)(x_1^2+p_1^2)-a(x_2^2+p_2^2) + (2ax_1 + ibp_1)x_2 + (2ap_1 - ibx_1)p_2} \log\left(2(x_2^2+p_2^2)-1\right). $$

The inner integral converges if $a > 0$, which of course follows from the assumption. Now by applying the polar coordinate change $(x_2,p_2)=(r_2\cos\theta_2,r_2\sin\theta_2)$ to the inner integral, we get

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}p_1 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r_2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta_2 \, r_2 e^{-(a-1)(x_1^2+p_1^2)-ar^2 + (2ax_1 + ibp_1)r_2\cos\theta_2 + (2ap_1 - ibx_1)r_2\sin\theta_2} \log\left(2r_2^2-1\right) \\
&= 2\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}p_1 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r_2 \, r_2 e^{-(a-1)(x_1^2+p_1^2)-ar^2} I_0\left(r_2\sqrt{(4a^2-b^2)(x_1^2 + p_1^2)}\right) \log\left(2r_2^2-1\right),
\end{align*}

where the integral with respect to $\theta_2$ is simplified using the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) and order 0. (See [DLMF.10.31.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E1) as well.)

Now it becomes clear that the outer integral converges when $a > 1$ as assumed in the beginning. Then applying the polar coordinate change $(x_1,p_1)=(r_1\cos\theta_1,r_1\sin\theta_1)$ and switching the order of integration, the well-known integral formula (see [DLMF.10.43.23](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43.E23), for instance) gives

\begin{align*}
I
&= (2\pi)^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r_2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r_1 \, r_1 r_2 e^{-(a-1)r_1^2-ar^2} I_0\left(r_1r_2\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}\right) \log\left(2r_2^2-1\right) \\
&= \frac{2\pi^2}{a-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r_2 \, r_2 e^{-\frac{b^2-4a}{4(a-1)}r_2^2} \log\left(2r_2^2-1\right).
\end{align*}

The last step reveals another condition required for the integral $I$ to converge, namely $b^2 > 4a$, which is also implied by the assumption. Then substituting $u=2r_2^2-1$ and letting

$$ s := \frac{b^2-4a}{8(a-1)}, $$

the integral simplifies by

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{\pi^2}{2(a-1)} \int_{-1}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}u \, e^{-s(u+1)} \log u \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{2(a-1)} e^{-s} \left( \int_{-1}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}u \, e^{-su} \log \left| u \right| + i\pi \int_{-1}^{0} \mathrm{d}u \, e^{-su} \right).
\end{align*}

Finally, by using the integration formula

$$ \int_{-1}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \, e^{-sx}\log \left|x\right| = -\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(s)}{s}, \qquad s > 0, $$

where $\operatorname{Ei}(s)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), we obtain:

$$ I = \frac{4\pi^2}{b^2-4a} e^{-s} \left( - \operatorname{Ei}\left(s\right) + i\pi \left( e^s - 1 \right) \right). $$

Comment: How did you take the last integral? When I try to take this integral numerically with very large upper boundary I always get a real number no matter what. You, however, got a complex contribution.

Comment: Also, physical dimensions don't work out (yes, its from physics). The dimensions should be b^-2 and/or a^-2. Temrs like 1/4a are unphysical. The answer cannot be fully correct. There is a mistake somewhere. Thanks though...

Comment: @MsTais, The argument of the logarithmic term in the integrand can assume negative values, so it is not surprising that we pick up imaginary value. And I must admit that the last step seems incorrect, mostly because I was exhausted at that moment and then soullessly threw the expression into Mathematica to get the final answer. I checked the final answer with the last integral and they do not agree numerically, so I will fix it soon. However, I double-checked all the other parts and they seem correct. I am pretty sure you may also replicate those computation using cited formulas by yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I am working on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MsTais, No problem! Also, note that the original integral converges only conditionally, and so, it is not entirely clear whether $$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\d x_1\d p_1\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\d x_2\d p_2\,\dots=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{[-N,N]^2}\d x_1\d p_1\int_{[-N,N]^2}\d x_2\d p_2\,\dots$$ holds. Indeed, there is a competition between the inner integral which becomes small for large $x_1$ and $p_1$ via high oscillation, and the outer integral which grow via the term $e^{x_1^2+p_1^2}$. They might result in different answers for different choices of orders and/or truncation methods.

Comment: That said, I cannot guarantee that the choice of the order of integration I made at the beginning is the physically right choice in your context. So I believe that your input on this choice is very critical toward the correct direction.

Comment: Yeah, I will do my best to work it out and will share if any updates. Thank you for the roadmap!